# Show the operator norm of $A^T A - I_n$ can be bounded by $3\max(\delta, \delta^2)$

Tags: matrices, singular-values, matrix-norms

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and $\delta>0.$ If all singular values of $A$ are between $1-\delta$ and $1+\delta$, $$1-\delta\leq s_n(A)\leq s_1(A) \leq 1+\delta,$$ prove $$\Vert A^TA-I_n\Vert \leq 3\max(\delta,\delta^2),$$where $s_1(A),\dots,s_n(A)$ are the singular values of $A$ and $s_1(A) \geq \cdots \geq s_n(A)$. Note that here the definition of the operator norm is $$\Vert A \Vert := \max_{x \in S^{n-1}\\ y \in S^{m-1}}\langle Ax,y\rangle=s_1(A).$$

---

So far, I have tried

$$\Vert A^TA-I_n\Vert = \Vert V(S^TS-I_n)V^T\Vert=s_1(A^TA-I_n).$$

But I am not sure how to connect with $3\max(\delta,\delta^2)$ . This is an extension exercise 4.1.6 from page 80 *[High-Dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)* by Roman Vershynin. Thank you!

---

> [image: print screen from the book]

Comment: Yes, it's the operator norm.

Comment: Then how to connect the relationship between $ s_1(A^TA-I_n)$ and $3\max(\delta,\delta^2)$? I am confused with the 3maximum part.

Comment: Do you mean $s1(A^TA-I_n)\leq (1+\delta^2)-1$? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106432/discussion-between-chen-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).

Comment: Since you're the one acquainted with the book: what do 2 coffee cups mean? I assume it's related to the level of difficulty. What is the maximum? 3 cups? 5 cups?

Comment: 4 cups.So far I only saw 4 cups once.

Comment: It seems that the way to solve this problem is to search the PDF copy of the book for "3" until one finds an arcane inequality that one can use to find the desired upper bound. Not a very interesting sport.

Answer (score 1):

We only need to prove for any $z \geq 0$,
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
     1 -\delta \leq z \leq 1+\delta \Rightarrow |z^2 - 1| \leq 3\max(\delta,\delta^2).
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
When $0<\delta \leq 1$, we have
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
     &(1-\delta)^2 \leq z^2 \leq (1+\delta)^2 \\
     \Rightarrow & -3\delta \leq -2\delta \leq  -2\delta + \delta^2 \leq z^2 - 1 \leq 2\delta + \delta^2 \leq 3\delta \quad (\delta^2 \leq \delta)\\
     \Rightarrow & |z^2 - 1| \leq 3\delta = 3\max(\delta, \delta^2). 
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
When $\delta > 1$, we have
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
     &1 -\delta < 0\leq  z \leq 1 + \delta \\
     \Rightarrow & 0 \leq z^2 \leq (1 + \delta)^2 \\
     \Rightarrow & -3\delta^2< -\delta^2 < -1 \leq z^2 - 1 \leq 2\delta + \delta^2 \leq 3\delta^2 \quad (\delta \leq \delta^2)\\
     \Rightarrow & |z^2 - 1| \leq 3\delta^2 = 3 \max(\delta,\delta^2).
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: note that $A^TA$ is symmetric, so has real eigenvalues. Can you bound them using the singular values of $A$ (if this isn’t obvious, use the SVD)? What happens when you subtract off the identity matrix? How does this relate to the operator norm?